# How can I get changed files list in my jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, git-diff

I'm trying to get all files that changed in my branch.
i tried many commands but found out that probably there is issue in my jenkins pipeline, no command return the correct list.

I wanna get the list from point i checked out the master, the master may got forwarded by others.

Locally there are some commands that return the correct changed files list:

```bash
git diff --name-only origin/master...   
git diff --name-only $(git merge-base HEAD origin/master)..
```

The list:

`e2e-v2/src/__specs__/alerts/alert-definitions.test.ts`

`tools/jenkins/e2e.groovy`

`tools/scripts/package.json`

from some reason, in Jenkins the return list is:

`tools/docker-collector-metrics/docker.yml`

`tools/docker-collector-metrics/system.yml`

`tools/jenkins/.env`

I cannot understand why it different.
Maybe there are some context issue?

Comment: Check what values are being used for each _commit_ involved there (with `git rev-parse`, for example: `git rev-parse HEAD origin/master`) in jenkins and the other place, then you could see if they are actually working on the same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a shell step in your Jenkins job

```
git log -10 --graph --decorate --oneline
git remote -v
git branch -avv
```

That would display the last 10 commits from HEAD, as well as the remote and branches checked out by your Jenkins job.

Do the same locally, and you can make sure you are in the same context/history or not.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your pipeline code?

I'm call a python file to execute this request `https://bitbucket.example.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/**project-name**/repos/**repo-name**/pull-requests/number-of-pullrequest/changes?limit=1000` (using bitbucket repo)

One more suggestion: you can try add clone your repository steps in pipeline, then execute the git command in the directory you clone repo.